# Reading IPs from txt file and connect to ftp in python

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm trying to write a script in python which connects to all our ftps and tells me that they are up and lists they dirs when connecting.

I'll try that with a file called "ips.txt" where all our ips are in - one each line and the following script:

```
import socket
import ftplib

username = "xxx"
password = "xxx"



for server in open("ips.txt", "r").readlines():
    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(server)
        welcome = ftp.getwelcome()
        print (welcome)

        try:
            attempt = ftp.login(user=username, passwd=password)
            success = ("[****] Working " + server + '\n')

            print(success)
            data = []
            ftp.dir(data.append)
            for lines in data:
                print (lines)

        except:
            print (server, username, password)
            pass

    except:
        print ("Timeout...")
```

But it seems like the script is skipping everything and just prints "Timeout..." :(

I'm a bloody python beginner, so please be patient.

EDIT:
After removing the outer try/except I got a traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp.py", line 12, in <module>
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(server)
  File "C:\Python3.5.1\lib\ftplib.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "C:\Python3.5.1\lib\ftplib.py", line 153, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python3.5.1\lib\socket.py", line 693, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python3.5.1\lib\socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

the ips.txt looks like:

```
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.11
10.10.10.21
10.10.10.33
```

So new line for each IP

Comment: Did you try printing the contents of `server` in each iteration to see what you are passing to the `FTP` class? Can you provide a few lines from your txt file as a sample?

Comment: Didnt try that.

the file just looks like:

10.10.10.10
10.10.10.11
10.10.10.19
...

Comment: Remove the outer `try/except` and you'll know what error pops up. `try/except`s are a debugger's nightmare.

Comment: Are the ip's delimited by space? Or newlines?

Comment: @alex I suggest you try printing out what `server` looks like in each iteration to help with some level of debugging. You might see right away what the problem is. Maybe you are taking extra characters you should not be taking. Or maybe what you are passing is not the full IP? Who knows. Update your question with an accurate example of your file. At least the first lines to understand.

Comment: @alex Please don't dump tracebacks, file contents, code in your comments. *please* update your question to make it more clear.

Comment: I printed (server) and it shows the right first row of the ips.txt. So the first ip.

Comment: As @SamChats mentioned `except :` is always a bad idea because can never know what error hit you, you should always specify what error(s) you expect to catch (like `except IndexError:`)

Comment: You are not stripping each line of its newline character. Do `server.strip()`.

Comment: Thats it! THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the file that you are providing, when you make a `readlines` call, you are still preserving the newline character at the end of each IP. This is most likely why you are getting the `gaierror` you are getting.

Replicating on my end, with a newline character, my traceback yields:

```
>>> FTP('10.10.10.10\n')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/ftplib.py", line 153, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 693, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Simply do:

```
FTP(server.strip())
```

You will then strip out the `\n` at the end of your IP and you should at the very least make the call to the *right* IP address.

Alternatively, you *could* try to see if `splitlines` works for you, considering you are dealing with a single list of IP addresses, it could be a good alternative.

[splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) will remove line breaks for you against a `string`, so you need to call `read` on your open object as well. Like this:

```
for server in open("ips.txt", "r").read().splitlines():
```